# Trying to compile GCC returns a bunch of errors

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-from-scratch

For the last hours I'm trying to compile GCC for LFS.

But it returns me this:

```
configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/intl':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details

make[2]: *** [makefile:9269: configure-stage2-intl] Error 77

make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'

make[1]: *** [makefile:24346: stage2-bubble] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'

make: *** [makefile:1033: all] Error 2
```

Here is my config.log:

https://mega.nz/file/QKxzlQZT#KhPkgTrDosGIc-_uCB2zhwJTb1nqfum6KOLg1IW-OAE

P.S. The error "C compiler cannot create executables" just does not exist there. Thx to mr. MadScientist for giving the idea of searching

i had to put it here because it just would not allow me to post as i'm going over the limits :)

So, honestly everything has been made everything by the book, but yet fails.

Comment: You should do as suggested, and _See `config.log' for more details_  If you can't figure it out from that, then find the _relevant part_ of the log file and cut and paste just that part with proper formatting into your question.  For example, find the error message above ("C compiler cannot create executables") and show the errors that were written to the log before that line.  Most people here aren't going to follow random links to some unknown site.  Usually this error means you don't have a C compiler installed at all, or else the compiler installation is broken somehow.

Comment: "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" Do you have already a suitable compiler installed? If not, that is the very first step. You can't build a compiler without a compiler... chicken egg problem :-) Maybe related to Easter eggs ?

Comment: Mr. Klaus, well.. i have a few, it detected g++. Also, i'm in an Orthodox country, so Easter's in two months (well almost) :)))

Comment: Mr. MadScientist, thing is that... well: the error just does NOT exist in any way in config.log.

Comment: In config.log you see what the configure scripts has tested. And you will see, why the script believes that the compiler is not working. you do not only g++, you also need gcc. Typically the compiler itself is both, only a symlink to one binary, but the rest of the installation may be corrupted? Take a deeper look into your log file please!

Comment: "C compiler cannot produce executables" generally indicates that `configure` selected a C compiler, but it failed to compile a test executable.  Thus, you should look into which compiler was selected.  That compilation attempt will have used compile and link options drawn from standard control variables `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, and perhaps others, so if any of those are set in the environment or specified explicitly to `configure` then the issue could be related to that.  In particular, you will get this error if the chosen compiler rejects an option drawn from one of those sources.

Comment: But I am not inclined to believe you when you say that configure's log does not report on the error.  Possibly you're looking at the wrong log, or possibly you're overlooking the relevant details, but Autotools `configure` scripts such as GCC's *do* log all the details of what `configure` does. I know from experience that they log details of this error in particular.